# Webpack: How to remove extra css classes from built out css file?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

Suppose I have one sass file named `common.scss`, suppose there are another 2 sass files, each named `chat.scss` and `thread.scss`, each of the 2 sass file import `common.scss` in the begining, like

```
@import 'common'
......
other self class definition codes
......
```

The case is, in build out production files phase, sometimes I only need to import `chat.scss`, but sometimes I need to import both `chat.scss` and `thread.scss`. When import both scss files, as you can see there will be extra class definition as each of them import `common.scss`. So I want to know is there any webpack plugin can remove extra class definition in build phase ?

Comment: Why don't you put these *other classes* into yet another scss files and `@import` them only when needed?

Comment: @ahwyX100 Have you tried [`optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin)?

Comment: @tony19 thanks, I think this should be worked.